# OpenID Connect single logout

Tags: connected-apps, oauth, open-id-connect, logout

I have a connected application (web site) that is using Salesforce as an authentication provider (OpenID Connect). And I'd like the logout on my site to work as a "single logout" - it should also log out the user from Salesforce.

According to [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_auth_slo_oidc_idp_configuring.htm&type=5), the user's browser should be redirected to this URL to perform the logout:

```
https://<domain>.my.salesforce.com/services/auth/idp/oidc/logout
```

This works fine (performs the logout), but the documentation fails to mention something like a redirect parameter. The problem is that the user will remain on salesforce.com after the logout, and I would really like to have a redirect back to my site.

All other OpenID Connect providers have something like a '?post_logout_redirect_uri=' parameter on the logout URL, but I failed to find something similar in Salesforce...

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

We are calling logout url in hidden iframe by passing by the logout url along with id_token, which logouts the Salesforce IDP.

```
var el = document.getElementById('ifrm');
el.src = logoutURL + 'id_token_hint=' +token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the answer yet ? I have also been trying to log the user out of Auth 0 on my community and to redirect the user back to community site with login.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/182448)